# Angular scope issues

Tags: angularjs, scope, directive

I have a question regarding scope in Angular.

I have a directive:

```
skillFoundry.directive('myPromotioncode', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        'close': '&onClose'
      },
      templateUrl: '/templates/my-promotioncode-close.html'
    };
});
```

under my controller I have the following "HTML" (Jade)

```
my-promotioncode.promotion_code(ng-hide="dialogIsHidden" on-close="hideDialog()")
  div.row 
   | Please enter your promotion code:
  div.col-xs-4    
    input.form-control(type="text", ng-model="promotionCode")
    {{promotionCode}}
  div.col-xs-4    
    a.btn-primary.btn-sm(ng-click="promotionCodeSubmit(promotionCode)") Submit
```

and in my controller , this function:

```
$scope.promotionCodeSubmit = function(theCode) {
    console.log("promotion code submit called !", this);
    var promotionCode = theCode;
    console.log("The promotion code is:" + promotionCode);
};
```

The function works as is, however, `$scope.promotionCode` is always undefined. I.e I should not have to passs in the value of promotionCode to the function. My understanding is that the `transclude` makes the current scope available to this and proceeding controllers ?

Why is `$scope.promotionCode` undefined ?

**EDIT:**

I realised the question was unclear and have restated, the function `$scope.promotionCodeSubmit` works as written above, however, what should also work, but does not is the following:

```
$scope.promotionCode = ""; /* init to something */

$scope.promotionCodeSubmit = function() {
    console.log("promotion code submit called !", this);
    var promotionCode = $scope.promotionCode;
    console.log("The promotion code is:" + promotionCode);
};
```

The `$scope.promotionCode` is not being correctly bound or there is a "scope" issue as it is not as expected within the controller.

Comment: where did you define `$scope.promotionCode` in controller, I don't see it.

Comment: If I define it e.g `$scope.promotionCode = "";` obviously it is no longer undefined, however is still not set to the expected value

Comment: Where do you call the function? Often you have to call `$scope.$apply();` to trigger another digest cycle for the changes to show up

Comment: Try to make a fiddle.

Comment: I thought transclude just deals with the template. Seems to me you have created an isolate scope here, and so you might need to map promotionCode into the directive's scope. Or easier might be to just remove the scope from your directive and let it inherit from the parent, then it could see promotionCode and the onClose function.

Comment: @aet what would the inherit syntax be, I want the directives `$scope` to be available in the enclosing controller ...

Comment: `scope: true` should do it for ya